# Upload Image to Amazon S3 dose not Working with the localHost?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

I want to upload an image to Amazon S3 while I'm on the LocalHost and the server gives me that error: "Access-Control-Allow-Origin"

Is there any solution for this error?

Note: I'm working with mvc 5 if that helps. I have removed the bucket name becuase it's too long.

Full Error: "XMLHttpRequest cannot load https://s3.amazonaws.com/747d522f-cf44-48e1-93e0-fa52d8ec29ed.jpg. Response to preflight request doesn't pass access control check: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. Origin 'http://localhost:50918' is therefore not allowed access. The response had HTTP status code 403."

Thank you :)

Comment: you are missing the bucket name

Comment: No I have removed it becuase it's too long thnak you :)